# C++: Why function is not found?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    writeFile();
}

int writeFile () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Why is this not working? it gives me the error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FileRead, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  file.cpp
1>e:\documents and settings\row\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\fileread\fileread\file.cpp(8): error C3861: 'writeFile': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and this is just a simple function. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 84):

There are two solutions to this. You can either place the method above the method that calls it:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int writeFile () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    writeFile();
}
```

Or declare a prototype:

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int writeFile();

int main()
{
    writeFile();
}

int writeFile () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i get the idea, there are so many languages, so it isn't **public static void main()** and **public void functionName()** ... hmm interesting ... and that part to put **main()** at the end is hilarious

Comment: Why is it "hilarious" to put the main function at the end? And what in the world is `public static void main()`? What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @Row Minds The essential idea here is that when you called writeFile() from main, the function writeFile has not been declared yet, hence the above solutions.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say the reason it's hilarious is that it's 20XX and we're still using a language that can't parse declarations then read definitions in a separate sweep. I don't find it hilarious, because I understand why it couldn't have been any other way. I simply weep.

Comment: what about if you wanted to display the value of the variable. I bet myfile << "%s\n", var; wont display any

Comment: @Juran: I think you meant `myfile << var << "\n";` That will work.

Answer (score 12):

Your `main` doesn't know about `writeFile()` and can't call it.

Move `writefile` to be before `main`, or declare a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) `int writeFile();` before `main`.

Answer (score 7):

You need to declare the **prototype** of your `writeFile` function, before actually using it:

```
int writeFile( void );

int main( void )
{
   ...
```

Comment: i get the idea, there are so many languages, so it isn't **public static void main()** and **public void functionName()** ... hmm interesting

Comment: Those are functions, not methods (class member functions). So there's no `public` concept here. `static` can be used for a function, meaning it will be private to the file. Note that you cannot do this for `main`, of course.

Comment: no public concept? how about public: and private: ?

Comment: Those specifiers can only be applied inside a class, in C++. Here, you don't have a class. Just functions, at the top-level.

Comment: i understand, it's strange ... btw, thanks

Comment: @RowMinds: It's only strange compared to Java and C#.  If you come from a more procedural language, then the concept of main being `public` or `static` is absolutely foreign.

Answer (score 7):

This is a place in which C++ has a strange rule. Before being able to compile a call to a function the compiler must know the function name, return value and all parameters.
This can be done by adding a "prototype". In your case this simply means adding before `main` the following line:

```
int writeFile();
```

this tells the compiler that there exist a function named `writeFile` that will be defined somewhere, that returns an `int` and that accepts no parameters.

Alternatively you can define first the function `writeFile` and then `main` because in this case when the compiler gets to `main` already knows your function.

Note that this requirement of knowing in advance the functions being called is not always applied. For example for class members defined inline it's not required...

```
struct Foo {
    void bar() {
        if (baz() != 99) {
            std::cout << "Hey!";
        }
    }

    int baz() {
        return 42;
    }
};
```

In this case the compiler has no problem analyzing the definition of `bar` even if it depends on a function `baz` that is declared later in the source code.

Comment: @RowMinds: C++ is not the result of a clean white page design, but comes from a long history of evolution that even got through a committee (and this alone can remove beauty from **anything**). In many parts unfortunately the result is quite surprising and apparently illogical... this also means that you cannot  trust your intuition when learning C++ and you must study it instead. It's a nice powerful language but its full of strange rules (that often are there just for historical reasons).

Comment: @RowMinds: C++ is a lower-level language and one of the main design choices was to remain close enough to the metal to leave no room for another language above assembler. Many thinks C++ failed at that (as C is often used instead of C++ for lower level parts) but still this decision influenced much of the design. C# is an higher level language so it doesn't really make sense to compare the two... each of them is better at something; if you need only what C# is good at then go for C#.

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration int writeFile () ; seems to be missing in the code.
Add int writeFile () ; before the function main()

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the functions or do a forward declaration of the writefiles function and it will work I think.