# save total number of frames of video file into a .txt file

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to save number of frames of video file into a .txt file . for example save the frame number from frame (0) until the last frame .I  can display the total frame numbers of a video file .

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <fstream>


using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Open video file
VideoCapture video("2.avi");

double fps = video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
double nframes = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT); 

cout << "Frames per second using video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) : " << fps << endl;
cout << "Frames count  : " << nframes << endl;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");

for (int i=0;i<nframes;i++)

{


myfile<< "Frame Number=  "<<";"<< i<< endl;

}    
myfile.close(); 
video.release(); 
return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of frames is

```
double nframes = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
```

fps is frames per second and tells you how fast a player should display the video and you can compute times if you know the time of the first frame.

To write data to a file you should search for writing to files in c++ and you'll find help in answers like [Simple file write function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863505/simple-file-write-function-in-c)

Comment: Thanks @Micka , I want the frames to be saved like ( 0,1,2,....) . this is my main question .

Comment: so you want to know "current frame number"? There is a property for that, too. Or you just count yourself.

Comment: for example if I have a video of 500 frames, I want to save number of frames starting from 0 to 4999

Comment: write a for loop from 0 to nframes and write to value in each iteration to file, for example with helo of a stringstream

Comment: Thanks @Micka , I have updated my code , is it correct now ?

Comment: now it should write to your file in each line: "FPS= ;0" "FPS= ;1" "FPS= ;2" and so on up to the total number of available frames -1. Not sure whether you want that (the word FPS confuses me because it normally is abbreviation for frames per second).